# Relationship between file in controller and button

Tags: magento2

I am newbie in Magento, I saw some sources and have a question is if we have an add product button in the interface add products as follows:
[image]

I also see that the NewAction file in the Controller that controls this button.

[image]

but I cann't find any relationship between the **add product button** and the **NewAction file**

> Is there a file naming convention in the controller that corresponds
>   to the button in Magento?

Can anyone answer this for me?

I would be very excited if you explain further me the Edit, MassDelete,...  files in the Controller.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New** is reserved keyword that's why magento add '**Action**' with new. So When you create a button, you need to assign action. In magento2 you can find following action controller:

1. For new entry 'new' and controller will be 'NewAction'
2. For edit it's edit and controller will be 'Edit'

and so on.

[Check following file how they convert this router](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Router/ActionList.php)

Following word are reserved, if you use any of them magento add after 'Action'

```
/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $reservedWords = [
    'abstract', 'and', 'array', 'as', 'break', 'callable', 'case', 'catch', 'class', 'clone', 'const',
    'continue', 'declare', 'default', 'die', 'do', 'echo', 'else', 'elseif', 'empty', 'enddeclare',
    'endfor', 'endforeach', 'endif', 'endswitch', 'endwhile', 'eval', 'exit', 'extends', 'final',
    'for', 'foreach', 'function', 'global', 'goto', 'if', 'implements', 'include', 'instanceof',
    'insteadof','interface', 'isset', 'list', 'namespace', 'new', 'or', 'print', 'private', 'protected',
    'public', 'require', 'return', 'static', 'switch', 'throw', 'trait', 'try', 'unset', 'use', 'var',
    'while', 'xor',
];
```

[Check this line where magento add 'action' string with reserver word](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Router/ActionList.php#L80)